# Oracle DataAccess Lock Code Stops

Tags: c#, oracle

When I use "Select ... for update" query code stops without exception or any freeze. It just won't go to the next instruction. It work fine for a regular select query. Any idea why ?

```
string selectQuery = "select * from table_name where id = 1 FOR UPDATE"; // Code stops on data fill
string selectQueryNoLock = "select * from table_name where id = 1"; // Code execute normally
string connectionString = "fake";
OracleConnection oracleConnection = new OracleConnection(connectionString);
Console.WriteLine("Open Connection");
oracleConnection.Open();
OracleTransaction oracleTransaction = oracleConnection.BeginTransaction();
OracleCommand oracleCommand = new OracleCommand(selectQuery, oracleConnection);
oracleCommand.Transaction = oracleTransaction;

OracleDataAdapter dataAdapter = new OracleDataAdapter(oracleCommand);
DataSet dataSet = new DataSet();
dataAdapter.Fill(dataSet);

// This line is never reached!
Console.WriteLine("Press any key...");
```

Comment: because another database connection already has a lock on that row in an on-going transaction?

Comment: No. I tried putting a break point on dataadapter.fill(dataSet) line, and execute an update on the same row from Oracle Sql Developper, the row isn't locked

Comment: This is probably too obvious to ask, but are you sure it isn't that open Oracle Sql Developer session which is holding the lock?  Try closing all your Oracle Sql Developer windows and try again.

Comment: Thanks. Actually closing everything isn't necesseray. I just have to commit on sql developper and then my code works a charm. Problem now is to handle rows already locked as there are absolutely no hint on what's going on. Should I start a new SO Question ?

Comment: Just as a hint, which may save you from having to ask a new question... you can also try adding a timeout on the `select ... for update`, like this: `select ... for update wait 10`.  That way, you get an exception after a certain amount of time if you are unable to acquire a lock.

Comment: @sstan Can you post your second comment as an answer so I can mark it corrrect ? And the wait 10 does the trick, thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A standard `select ... for update` will wait indefinitely if another transaction is currently holding a lock on that row.  In normal apps, this is not really a problem, as transactions should be short-lived.

However, if an indefinite wait is not the behavior that you want, and you would rather be told if you are unable to acquire a lock after a certain amount of time, you can specify a timeout like this:

```
select ... for update wait 10
```

... which will return an error if the timeout elapses and you are unable to acquire the lock.

Alternatively, if you don't want to wait at all, you can also do:

```
select ... for update nowait
```

... which will immediately return an error if you can't acquire the lock right away.